# Using CSV string Values in 'IN' clause of Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which accepts csv string as the parameter , for eg. ('IN\libin.jose,IN\Pallabi.P'). Stored procedure contains some dynamic sql which make use of this parameter inside IN clause eg : (AND u1.UserName IN (' + @UserNames + ')). Since this is being inside dynamic sql ,The condition is not passing without appending extra single quotes to the CSV values eg        ('''IN\libin.jose ''  ,''IN\Pallabi.P''')

```html
--exec [GetUwParameterDetails] 'IN\libin.jose,IN\Pallabi.P' , 'false'
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUwParameterDetails]

@UserNames nvarchar(max),
@IncludeInactiveusers bit

AS
BEGIN

declare @selectedUsers nvarchar(max)
--set @selectedUsers = '''IN\libin.jose '' ,''IN\Pallabi.P''';
set @selectedUsers = 'IN\libin.jose,IN\Pallabi.P';
declare @selectedPermissions nvarchar(max)
set @selectedPermissions = '''Underwrite'',''ManageUwTeamPipeline''';

DECLARE @parameterQuery1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX);



set @parameterQuery1 = '

;WITH cte_users
AS (
 SELECT users.id
  ,users.UserName
  ,users.FirstName
  ,users.lastname
  ,users.Email
  ,users.E3UserName 
  ,UserStatus.[Status]
  ,Widgets.[Description] DefaultWidget
 FROM users 
 INNER JOIN userparametervalues upv ON users.id = upv.userid
 INNER JOIN Parameters p on upv.ParameterId = p.id 
  AND p.Name = ''UwHierarchy''
 INNER JOIN UserPermissions up ON users.id = up.userid
 INNER JOIN [Permissions] ps on up.PermissionId = ps.Id 
  AND ps.IsActive = 1 AND ps.Name IN ('+ @selectedPermissions +')
 INNER JOIN users AS u1 ON upv.value = u1.id
  AND u1.UserName IN (' + @UserNames + ') 
    INNER JOIN UserStatus ON users.StatusId = UserStatus.Id
 LEFT JOIN Widgets ON users.WidgetId = Widgets.Id )select * from cte_users ';
 exec @parameterQuery1

 END
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this after BEGIN

```
set @UserNames =''''+replace(@usernames,',',''',''')+''''
```